# Apex Batch Job Start and Execute are not ran (no debug statements from them showing up)

Tags: salesforce, batch-processing, apex

My batch job class is as follows:

```
global class GroupMemberSearch implements Database.Batchable<SObject>{

global String groupQuery;
global final Map<Id, Group> groupIdMap;

global GroupMemberSearch(String groupQuery){
    system.debug(groupQuery);
    this.groupQuery = groupQuery;
}

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    system.debug('In batch start');
    return Database.getQueryLocator(groupQuery);
}
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<SObject> scope){
    system.debug(scope);
    List<groupInfo> grpMemberList = new List<groupInfo>();
    for(Group s : (List<Group>)scope){
        system.debug(s);
        groupInfo newGroup = new groupInfo();
        if(s.Name != null){
            set<Id> memberIdSet = getGroupMembers(new set<Id>{s.Id}, 0);
            if(memberIdSet.size() != 0){
                newGroup.groupId = s.Id;
                newGroup.groupName = s.Name;
                newGroup.groupMemberIds = memberIdSet;
                grpMemberList.add(newGroup);
            }
        }
    }
    system.debug(grpMemberList);
}
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){}

private set<Id> getGroupMembers(set<Id> groupIds, Integer queryLimit){
    set<Id> nestedIds = new set<Id>();
    set<Id> returnIds = new set<Id>();
    if(queryLimit < 5){
    List<GroupMember> members = [SELECT Id, GroupId, UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMember WHERE GroupId IN :groupIds];
    for(GroupMember member : members){
        if(Schema.Group.SObjectType == member.UserOrGroupId.getSObjectType()){
            nestedIds.add(member.UserOrGroupId);
        } else{
            returnIds.add(member.UserOrGroupId);
        }
    }
    }
    queryLimit++;
    if(nestedIds.size() > 0){
        returnIds.addAll(getGroupMembers(nestedIds, queryLimit));
    }
    return returnIds;
}

public class groupInfo{
    public String groupId;
    public String groupName;
    public set<Id> groupMemberIds;
}
}
```

And in my apex controller, I call

```
Id batchProcessId = Database.executeBatch(new GroupMemberSearch('SELECT Id, OwnerId, Name, Email FROM Group WHERE Name != null'), 20);
```

which returns a batch Id, and I see the system.debug from the apex batch job constructor... However, I don't see any system.debugs from the start and execute methods... I restricted my log to show only debug statements and they were not in there anywhere. I know my query returns a list of groups, even if it didn't, I should still see the system.debug from the start method before the return...

I want this batch job ran when the page is loaded, thus it is in the constructor of the apex controller.

Any idea why the start and execute methods are not being ran??

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Does the query you are running have records? looks like getQueryLocator is returning 0 records, probably is the reason why you don't see logs. also, check on Setup > Apex Jobs if your batch execution has records.